# invoking functions defined by flet in another function

Tags: lisp, elisp

I have a collection of functions defined in `foo` that I want to also want to use in `bar`. I have these functions defined in `foo` because I want `foo` to be self-contained -- otherwise I know that I can define these functions externally (globally) to be accessible to `foo` and `bar` and other functions, or define both `foo` and `bar` within a `labels` construct in which these functions are defined only for `foo` and `bar`. In any case, I would like for `foo` to be distributable without the external functions or the `labels` structure. Hence the challenge.

This is what I have so far (I am using Emacs Lisp in this case), but what I have now ends up defining the local functions in `foo` globally when I invoke `bar`. Any suggestions how to define local variables/functions in `bar` "on the fly"?

```
(defun foo (x)
  (flet ((addone (x) (1+ x))
     (addtwo (x) (+ 2 x)))
    (addtwo x)))

(defun bar (x) 
  (let* ((fnlist (car (cdaddr (symbol-function 'foo))))
     (nfn (length fnlist))
     (ifn nil)
     (bar-body '(addone x))
     (i 0))
    (eval (append 
       ;; local symbol names
       ;; to which function definitions will be set
       (list 'let (mapcar 'car fnlist))
       ;; set function definitions
       (list '(while (< i nfn)
            (setq ifn (nth i fnlist))
            (eval `(fset ',(car ifn) ,(append (list 'lambda) (cdr ifn))))
            (setq i (1+ i))))
       ;; function invocation
       (list bar-body)))))
```

Function application:

```
(foo 1) ;;=> 3

(bar 1) ;;=> 2

(addone 1) ;;=> 2 ?should not be defined outside of bar?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs Lisp has dynamic binding. This is different from the lexical binding used by pretty much all other Lisps. For example, if you try to do the following in Common Lisp, you will get an error message saying that `FOO` is not defined:

```
(defun bar ()
  (foo 10))

(flet ((foo (x) (1+ x)))
  (bar))
```

In Emacs Lisp, however, since FOO is dynamically bound this will return 11 as the binding of `FOO` is available in `BAR`.

Emacs Lisp does not provide lexical bindings for functions, so in order to achieve the same thing in Emacs Lisp you'll have to fake it by binding a lambda to a lexical variable and then use a macro to hide the `FUNCALL`:

```
(lexical-let ((foo #'(lambda (x) (1+ x))))
  (macrolet ((foo (x) `(funcall foo ,x)))
    (foo 10)))
```

The other answer to this question suggests the use of a macro instead of the `flet`. This works, but it results in unnecessary code duplication. My solution prevents this at the expense of having to either write the `macrolet` part, or using `funcall` every time you want to call the function. One could write a macro to wrap all of this inside a lexical `flet` version if this is something that is needed often.

Comment: Hi @Elias, in Emacs Lisp lexical scoping of functions is permitted by the use of the `labels` macro I believe. But isn't the way I had defined a local variable with `let` and assigned a lambda expression to it equivalent to the approach you suggest, calling the function with `funcall` and `macrolet`?... Perhaps I am missing an important conceptual link. Thanks...

Comment: In Emacs Lisp, `let`, `labels` and `flet` has dynamic scope. That means that if you bind a variable using any of these methods, those variables/functions will be available in any functions that are called from its body.

The workaround is to use `lexical-let` which fakes proper lexical bindings. This prevents the definition to leak out. The `macrolet` trick is just to provide normal call semantics in order to avoid having to type `(funcall foo 10)`.

Comment: Thanks -- got it. Brilliant. Except it's unfortunate that it is not as straightforward as I had initially imagined.

Comment: Actually, it turns out you're right. `labels` is in fact lexically scoped in Emacs Lisp. I'll just attribute that to yet more inconsistencies in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't self-contained, so it's not really an answer; but it's different to the other options you mentioned, so I'll add it anyway.

```
(defmacro with-foo-functions (&rest forms)
  `(flet ((addone (x) (1+ x))
          (addtwo (x) (+ 2 x)))
     ,@forms))

(defun foo (x)
  (with-foo-functions
   (addtwo x)))

(defun bar (x)
  (with-foo-functions
   (addone x)))
```

Comment: Macros! I need to learn about these. I will definitely keep these in mind -- thank you!

Comment: I would, personally, have used an `&body forms` in the arglist and `'@forms` in the template.

Comment: Good call, although I assume that you meant to say `&rest forms` and `,@forms`? I've edited that into the answer.

Comment: @phils: I actually meant &body, it performs the same role as &rest in a macro lambda list, but allows sufficiently-aware editors to infer that the body should have "progn-like" indentation instead of "hanging args to a funcall" indentation. I did indeed mean `,@forms`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Does Emacs lisp support that, though? It's not mentioned in the elisp info pages, and I can't get it to work as a substitute for `&rest`.